# Printing a pattern through the use of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash-map, ascii-art

We had to port a program from c to python.  The code works but uses a dictionary to solve the problem.  This doesn't feel like the right use of a dictionary.  Is there a better way?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def main():
    while True:
        height = input("Height: ")
        try:
            height = int(height)
            if height >= 0:
                break
        except:
            pass
   
    mtn={}
    space_mtn(height,mtn)
    hashs_mtn(height,mtn)
    print_mtn(height,mtn)
    
def space_mtn(height,mtn):
    
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(2*height+2):
            mtn[i,j]=" "
    return 

def hashs_mtn(height,mtn):

    for i in range(height):
        for  j in range(height-1,height-i-2,-1):
            mtn[i,j] = '#'
    
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(height+2,height+i+3):
            mtn[i,j] = '#'
    return

def print_mtn(height,mtn):
    
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(height+3+i):
            print("{}".format(mtn[i,j]),end="")
        print("")
    return 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For how you're using it, it seems like a `list` of `list`s would make more sense than a `dict`. This is somewhat like a 2-dimensional array in C.

Your `mtn` initialization becomes:

```
mtn = []
```

You'll need to do a little more work in `space_mtn` to generate the sublists:

```
def space_mtn(height,mtn):
    for i in range(height):
        mtn.append([])             # Append an empty sublist at each level
        for j in range(2*height+2):
            mtn[-1].append(" ")    # Append a space to the end of the currently-last list
    return
```

Now in `hash_mtn` and `print_mtn`, just change your `mtn[i,j]` calls to `mtn[i][j]`.

Now, there are lots of ways to make this code less C-like and more idiomatic python, or "Pythonic". I'll just say that it's possible (although not necessarily "best") to get equivalent functionality by replacing everything after your input `while` loop with one line:

```
print('\n'.join('{0:>{1}}  {0:{1}}'.format('#'*(i+1), height) for i in range(height)))
```

Comment: thanks. when you mtn[-1].append(" ") are you placing a space inside of the last mtn([])?

Comment: @DCR Yes, `mtn[-1]` means "the last item in `mtn`".

Comment: I got that I just wanted to make sure I understood.  You're creating a list item and then placing a space in that list

Answer (score -2):

Dictionaries are great. As long as you don't care about a specific order (though there are ways of making them ordered and I believe they will be in a upcoming release of python).

In your case maybe the use of [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) could be useful.

Comment: Dictionaries being ordered is also considered an implementation detail. If you need an ordered mapping use `OrderedDict` to always be safe.

Comment: **Please see** [ask] **and** [answer]